# Google Sheets script to match values of cells unexpectedly not working

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script to remove duplicates from a spreadsheet.

I take all the values from a column and put them into an array using getValues(). I then use a for loop to compare array[i] with array[i+1]. If a match is found some code is executed which deletes the offending data.

Unfortunately no match is ever found.

I've tried my code on arrays that I inputted manually, it worked. I then tried my code to compare a manually coded array with the spreadsheet populated array; it worked again. The issue comes when I try to compare spreadsheet values with other spreadsheet values. They never match. What on Earth is going on?

```
function RemoveDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var IDRangeString = "H2:H"+ getFirstEmptyRow();
  var IDRange = sheet.getRange(IDRangeString);
  var IDArray = IDRange.getValues();
  Logger.log('started RemoveDuplicates(), active sheet is ' + sheet.getName() 
+ ', specified range is ' + IDRangeString);

  for(var i = 0; i < IDArray.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('comparing index ' + i + ': ' + IDArray[i] + ' with index ' + 
(i+1) + ': ' + IDArray[i+1]);

    if(IDArray[i] == IDArray[i+1]) {
      Logger.log('Match Found');
    } else if(IDArray[i] != IDArray[i+1]) {
      Logger.log('Match not found');
    } else {
      Logger.log('Match neither found nor not found');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved the problem but I still have no idea why it didn't work in the first place.

Using Array[i].toString() and comparing those values seemed to do the trick.

I can only assume that they were stored as different types of variable, but considering I checked it by typing in some identical values manually to the spreadsheet I don't know how.

Comment: Get values function returns a 2D array, whereas you are trying to compare 1D array in the above code. Array[I].tostring essentially converts each array at index I to a string and you are able to check the array. You can try this instead array[i][0] == array[i+1][0].